# Can't display list of object

Tags: asp.net-core

So I want to display a list of employees with various welfares that related to by a Many-Many relationship. Right now I'm stuck at display a list of welfare related to employee. It displays only the first item and then stops. It not only won't show the rest welfare but also every info of other employee.

Json:
`[{"employeeID":1,"employeeName":"Manh","welfareEW":[{"employeeID":1 ...`

My Code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Json(_db.employee.Include(x => x.welfareEW).ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Seems related more to .net core than angular. Anyways can you confirm that it actually returns more than 1 item when you put a break point in your .net core project? It might be cause due to circular reference object.

Comment: @penleychan Oh yes, I'm sorry about that. I have some question previously but ended up figure out while writing question in here and kinda forget it. The item you mention here is "employee" right?  I can assure you that I can return a full list of them. I try using Include method to display welfare also and it failed.

Comment: Is the JSON actually malformed as in your example or did you not copy/paste it properly? If the former, check your console as you almost surely would have an exception.

Comment: @Dean It is like that. I am not joking when I said it's "literally stop". It's end right after the first value like there's something blocking it but it won't return any error so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Well, that's tough to troubleshoot remotely without being able to reproduce it. Do you perhaps have a global exception handler that is swallowing the exception / attempting to deal with it gracefully?

Comment: @Dean No, sadly I have none of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may come across circular reference between `Employee` and `Welfare`.

To prevent Reference Looping ,you could use below code in startup ConfigureServices:

For asp.net core 2.2:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

For asp.net core 3.0 (MVC/Web API), just follow below steps to overcome circular reference using NewtonsoftJson.

1.Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package(version depends on your project)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.0.0
```

2.Add below code in `startup.cs`

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(x =>
        {
            x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, thats need a where clause to get welfares for each employeeID.

```
_db.employee.Include(x => x.welfareEW)
    .Select(x => new {
          employeeID = x.emplyeeID, 
          emplyeeName = x.employeeName,
          welfareEW = x.welfareEW?
              .Where(y => y.employeeID == x.employeeID)
              .ToList()
        })
    .ToList()
```

Hope this could helps.